# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException when using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this program to reverse the order of words, but the input is messed up. This is my output log.

```
1
this is a trial
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Store_Credit.main(Store_Credit.java:13)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And, here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse_Words {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N;
        N = scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int h  = i+1;
            String[] s = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            System.out.print("Case #"+h+": ");
            for(int j = s.length-1; j >=0; j++) {
                System.out.print(s[j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You stacktrace doesn't match your code

Comment: `Scanner.nextInt()` consumes the number you type in but _not_ the carriage return.  The return is consumed by your call to `Scanner#nextLine()`.

Comment: That exception is not thrown for the input  you've shown. Another one is thrown, though. Are you really entering 1 and pressing enter when executing this?

Comment: @Tim and the codes only calls split on the carriage return, which isn't an exception

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah maybe this actually runs?

Comment: I second cricket_007: your stack trace is for Store_Credit.java, and you've posted the code of Reverse_Words.java.

Comment: This isn't the correct class! `at Store_Credit.main`. Please show that, if you want help @Deep

Comment: To update your question with proper code which matches stack-trace use [edit] option placed below your question (or to be more precise below tags).

Comment: To reverse a string  `new StringBuider("TextHere").reverse().toString()`

Comment: @Tilak Question wants to reverse the words not the characters

Comment: Thank you! @cricket_007. I was running the wrong class

Answer (score -1):

try executing this and check if you still get errors

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.println("enter number");
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int h  = i+1;

            System.out.println("enter string");

            String[] s = scanner1.nextLine().split(" ");
            System.out.print(s.length);
            System.out.print("Case #"+h+": ");
            for(int j = s.length-1; j >=0; j--) {
                System.out.print(s[j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

decrement j value in the last for loop ie., j-- (not j++)

Comment: The code in the question isn't throwing the mentioned errors. Having two Scanners is unnecessary

Comment: Yup you are right. I realize that. Since I wasn't getting the above said errors I wasn't exactly sure what was wrong with the code. So I gave a code that runs correctly.

Comment: i think i figured it out. place a scanner.nextLine() after your scanner.nextInt(). Problem is nextInt() doesnt take return. and the nextLine() takes the number n you type as well as the string you type. so adding another scanner.nextLine() helps.